# Probability of drawing 4 aces when drawing 5 cards from a regular deck of cards.

Tags: probability

I cannot seem to wrap my head around how to calculate the probability of drawing four ace when drawing five cards from a deck of cards. My intuition tells me the math below but its wrong for some reason...

$
\frac{\frac{4}{52}\frac{3}{51}\frac{2}{50}\frac{1}{49}C^{48}_{1}5!}{C^{52}_{5}}.$

$\frac{4}{52}\frac{3}{51}\frac{2}{50}\frac{1}{49}$ is the probability of drawing the four aces.

$C^{48}_{1}$ is all the different combinations we can draw all other cards

$5!$ are all the combinations that this can happen. For example, we can draw any card but an ace first, then four aces. We can draw an ace then the other three aces and some card, and so on. Thus we get 5 factorial.

$C^{52}_{5}$ is all of the combinations one can draw five cards from a deck of cards.

What is wrong with my reasoning and equation above?

It seems from other examples online that if we draw one type of ace (let's say heart) it does not matter that there are three other types of ace nor that we could draw a card that is not an ace at a certain other index (second, third fourth card, etc). How come?

From other posts and my textbook it seems that we can just assume we drew four ace and then we calculate the remaining cards. That yields the equation: $\frac{1*C^{48}_{1}}{C^{52}_{5}}$ where the $1$ is the fact that we are going to draw four ace so we can assume we already have. I am confused about where the different combinations of aces go and the different combinations in which we draw them together with the "extra" non ace card.

I have specified the apparent solution in the above paragraph. It has been given on multiple occasions throughout stackexchange and other parts of the internet. What these answers do not do is explain WHY.

Comment: @KurtG. No it does not. I still do not understand why the order of the aces do not matter. How should the question be modified to reflect that different ways of selecting four aces are different outcomes and we want to calculate each one of them? In what way does the original question specify that these combinations are superfluous? These are questions I in my post (indirectly) that are not answered elsewhere. I am not looking for the solution I am looking for an explanation because I simply do not understand the answer.

Comment: (1) Do not repeat one question, in bf, four times.  (2) One question per post, please. (3) The main question has already been answered in a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be solved in two ways.  We can either take the order of selection into account or not take it into account.

*Taking the order of selection into account*:  There are $52 - 4 = 48$ ways to select the card which is not an ace.  There are $5!$ ways to arrange the four aces and that card.  There are $P(52, 5) = \binom{52}{5}5!$ ways to select five cards in order.  Hence, the probability of selecting four aces when five cards are drawn is
$$\Pr(\text{all four aces are selected}) = \frac{48 \cdot 5!}{P(52, 5)} = \frac{48 \cdot 5!}{\dbinom{52}{5} \cdot 5!} = \frac{48}{\dbinom{52}{5}}$$

*Not taking the order of selection into account*:  We must select all four aces and one of the other $48$ cards in the deck while selecting five of the $52$ cards in the deck.  Hence, the probability of selecting four aces is
$$\Pr(\text{all four aces are selected}) = \frac{\dbinom{4}{4}\dbinom{48}{1}}{\dbinom{52}{5}} = \frac{48}{\dbinom{52}{5}}$$

*What is wrong with your calculation?*

If you take the order of selection into account in the numerator, you must also take it into account in the denominator.  Also, in your numerator, you multiplied the probability of selecting four aces by the number of ways of selecting a non-ace.  You need to multiply the number of ways of taking all four aces by the number of ways of selecting a non-ace.

**Addendum:**  Here is another way of handling the ordered selection.  There are $48$ ways to select the non-ace.  There are four ways to select the first ace, three ways to select the second ace, two ways to select the third ace, and one way to select the fourth ace.  We will consider cases, depending on the position of the non-ace.
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{all four aces are selected}) & = \frac{4}{52} \cdot \frac{3}{51} \cdot \frac{2}{50} \cdot \frac{1}{49}  \cdot \frac{48}{48} + \frac{4}{52} \cdot \frac{3}{51} \cdot \frac{2}{50} \cdot \frac{48}{49}  \cdot \frac{1}{48}\\
& \quad + \frac{4}{52} \cdot \frac{3}{51} \cdot \frac{48}{50} \cdot \frac{2}{49}  \cdot \frac{1}{48} + \frac{4}{52} \cdot \frac{48}{51} \cdot \frac{3}{50} \cdot \frac{2}{49}  \cdot \frac{1}{48}\\
& \qquad + \frac{48}{52} \cdot \frac{4}{51} \cdot \frac{3}{50} \cdot \frac{2}{49}  \cdot \frac{1}{48}\\
& = \frac{5 \cdot 48 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{52 \cdot 53 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48}\\[2 mm]
& = \frac{48 \cdot 5!}{\frac{52!}{47!}}\\[2 mm]
& = \frac{48 \cdot 5!}{\frac{52}{47!5!} \cdot 5!}\\[2 mm]
& = \frac{48 \cdot 5!}{\binom{52}{5}5!}\\[2 mm]
& = \frac{48}{\binom{52}{5}}
\end{align*}
which agrees with the answer obtained above by first selecting the five cards and then arranging them.

Comment: In the first way you have "Pr(all four aces are selected)". Why? Nowhere in the question are the four aces selected and are to be arranged with the other non-ace cards of the deck. Same with the second way. All you are doing in the second way is just saying "Somehow we already selected the Ace's and now we have 48 cards left to combine this magically created group with.

Comment: There is only one way to select all four aces: $\binom{4}{4} = 1$.  There are $48$ ways to select the other card from among the other $48$ cards in the deck.  Hence, there are $48$ ways to select five cards from the deck if all four aces are included up to the order of selection.  If we care about the order in which these five cards are selected, there are $5!$ to arrange them.

Comment: There might be only one way to select all four aces but how probable is it that we get that particular selection of four items out from 52 total items? Where does the probability go? Some people talk about the cards in groups "One way to select four cards" others in probability "4/52" but what about that order with that probability?

Comment: When I took order into account, I first selected the five cards in the hand, then arranged them.  I have added another method of solution that makes the order of selection more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

In your attempt, you are mixing up probabilities and # of ways

If you want to use probability the way you tried, the ans would just be

$Pr = \dfrac4{52}\dfrac3{51}\dfrac2{50}\dfrac1{49}\dfrac{48}{48}\times5\quad$
[The $5$ multiplier for the $5$ places for non-ace]

The book's answer counts ways using the hypergeometric distribution
It would have been clearer if written as $\dfrac{\binom44\binom{48}1}{\binom{52}5}$

Please remember, numerators and denominators must match in type

Comment: Why am I not looking for the probability of all the different ways I can succeed? Is probability not (at times such as this) connected to the # of ways something can happen? I can succeed in this task of drawing cards in one way and some other person can succeed in another way. The probability is the same but the different outcomes are (same but different) different.

Comment: Direct computation of probability drawing 2 red, 1 blue from an urn having two of each. RRB *Pr* is $\frac24\frac13\frac12$, but it could be $RBR$ or $ BRR$ so a **multiplier** of $3$ is needed, **no divisor**

Answer (score 1):

If the aces and any one of the card are in a fixed order for example heart, diamond, club, spade, any card.

$$P(\text{fixed order})=\frac{1}{52}\times \frac{1}{51}\times \frac{1}{50}\times \frac{1}{49}\times \frac{48}{48}$$

But if they can be in any order then

$$P(\text{in any order})=\frac{1}{52}\times \frac{1}{51}\times \frac{1}{50}\times \frac{1}{49}\times \frac{48}{48}\times 5!$$

Comment: Any mistake for -1

Comment: You have $\frac{1}{52}$ it should be the number of ace left over the total number of cards.

Comment: @riemanneru Lion Heart got $1/52$ for the probability of choosing the ace of hearts first, like it says in the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the problem in the following way:

Assume that aces are cards of type $A$ and others are of type $B$. So, you have 4 cards of type $A$ and 48 cards of type $B$. You want to choose 4 cards of type $A$ and 1 card of type $B$. Hence the answer is

$$\dfrac{\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{1}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

Comment: The issue I have with this answer is probably best explained with an example: "What is the probability of getting first a four and then a five with a regular dice in two throws?" With your method the first output is just 1 over 1, because the outcome "getting a four" is its own type. Then the second one is 6 over 1 because we can only get a five from the six options. Does that make sense? No. I do not understand...

Comment: @riemanneru You are comparing an ordered selection with this answer's unordered selection.  In an unordered selection, we only care about which cards are selected, not the order in which they are selected.

Comment: @riemanneru I think you are calculating the number of ways instead of the probability... The probability of getting a four is 1 **over 6**. You forgot the 6 in denominator.